# Haskell map until first condition met

Tags: haskell

I want to map a conditional function only on the first item that passes.

```
map (>5) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

would result in

```
[False,False,False,False,False,True,True,True,True]
```

I'm looking for something that would result in

```
[False,False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False]
```

So only the first occurrence of being greater than 5 results in True.
I tried scanl, various folds and tried to roll my own mapUntil kind of thing. 
Seems like a simple problem but I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: You have made a tactical error, I think. You thought up a possible intermediate result that might help you do the thing you actually care about and described the intermediate output of `[False, False, ..., True, False, False, ...]`. Almost all the answers latched onto that, and tried to help build that function. But whatever you're doing, I'm willing to bet 10:1 that using that intermediate result is going to be much more convoluted than just doing it directly. Tell us what you *really* want to do.

Comment: Daniel Wagner, you are probably correct. See lines 62 to 66 of 
https://code.world/haskell#PCwtX5x7eU80ctnxHByG8_w
and you will see what I was trying to do.

Comment: Proposal: make `getCircleDragged :: Maybe Int`, with the `Int` representing an index into the list of circles that is the one being dragged (if any). Then use `findIndex` to create that field on line 60.

Comment: I have added an extention to my answer to cover your real problem. I think `mapAccumL` is a concise way to do this job.

Comment: I'm going to try both of these and see what works best. The reason for wanting the first index is I only want one circle to be drag-able even if more than one are under the cursor.

Comment: I refactored my code to use a Maybe Int instead of [Bool] as suggested and it got 10 lines shorter and can now accommodate any number of circles.
I appreciate all the answers given as much was learned and someone googling a similar problem will find something of value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**break** specifically separates the list in 2 parts where the first part is all `False`, the opposite of **span**.

```hs
break (>5) [1,2,3,8,2,5,1,7,9]
>>> ([1,2,3],[8,2,5,1,7,9])
```

Then it's just what chi did:

```hs
oneTrue f lst  = map (const False) a ++ rest b
   where (a,b) = break f lst
         rest [] = []
         rest (x:xs) = True : map (const False) xs
```

Comment: break function makes it simple, so accepted this answer.

Answer (score 4):

A basic solution:

```
mapUntil p = onlyOne . map p
   where 
   onlyOne []     = []
   onlyOne (x:xs)
     | x         = True  : map (const False) xs
     | otherwise = False : onlyOne xs
```

With library helpers:

```
mapUntil p = snd . mapAccumL (\x y -> (x||y, not x && y)) False . map p
```

Above `x` is a boolean standing for "have seen a true before?", as a kind-of state. `y` is the list element. `x||y` is the new state, while `not x && y` is the new list element.

Alternatively (using `Control.Arrow.second`):

```
mapUntil p = uncurry (++) . second go . break id . map p
   where
   go [] = []
   go (x:xs) = x : map (const False) xs
```

Comment: Doesn't `fmap` do precisely what `second` does in this case?

Comment: @FrownyFrog Yes, it does. I think `second` is a bit more understandable in this context, but it's a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the [`mapAccumL`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL) tool like;

```
λ> Data.List.mapAccumL (\b n -> if b then (b, (not b)) else (n > 5, n > 5)) False [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
(True,[False,False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False])
```

Here we carry the `b` as the state of our interim calculations and in every step decide according to it's previous state. Obviously you need the `snd` part of the final result.

**Edit :** After reading the new comment of @Gord under his question I decided to extend my answer to cover his true problem.

Rephrasing the `case event of` branch that starts with `pointerPress (x,y)` into...

To start with, you never use `x` or `y` from the pattern match `(x,y)` so lets call it `c`. Then...

```
 PointerPress c -> State circleCoords circleColors circleDraggeds c
   where
   bools = fmap checkMouseOverlaps $ (,) <$> circleCoords <*> [c]
   circleDraggeds = snd $ mapAccumL (\a b -> if a then (a, not a)
                                                  else (b,b)) False bools
```

What's happening part;

`(,) <$> circleCoords <*> [c]`

`circleCoords` is a list of coordinates like `[c0,c1,c2]` and we `fmap` (the infix version `(<$>)` here) `(,)` function to it and it becomes an applicative of coordinates like `[(c0,),(c1,),(c2,)]`. Then we apply it to `[c]` aka `[(x,y)]` to turn it into `[(c0,c),(c1,c),(c2,c)]`.

`fmap checkMouseOverlaps $ toAbove`

obviously yields to

```
[checkMouseOverlaps (c0,c), checkMouseOverlaps (c1,c), checkMouseOverlaps (c2,c)]
```

which is `bools :: [Bool]`.

The the rest follows the logic explained at the top of my answer.

```
circleDraggeds = snd $ mapAccumL (\a b -> if a then (a, not a)
                                               else (b,b)) False bools
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solve directly with recursion. Similar to chi's solution but without function composition

```
mapUntil :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Bool]
mapUntil _ [] = []
mapUntil f (x:xs) = 
  let b = f x                         -- calculate f x
  in if b                             -- if true 
      then b : map (const False) xs   -- prepend to the solution and map False to the rest of the list (b is True)
      else b : mapUntil f xs          -- keep applying mapUntil (b is False)

>>> mapUntil (>5) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[False,False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Map the condition over the list, then [zip](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) the result with the `False` prefix of the result concatenated with a `True` followed by an infinite list of `False`s:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BlockArguments, ApplicativeDo, ViewPatterns #-}

import Control.Applicative (ZipList(..))

f :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Bool]
f cond (map cond -> bs) = getZipList do
    r <- ZipList $ takeWhile not bs ++ [True] ++ repeat False
    _ <- ZipList $ bs
    pure r
```

or, equivalently:

```
f' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Bool]
f' cond (map cond -> bs) = zipWith const (takeWhile not bs ++ [True] ++ repeat False) bs
```

Comment: This assumes `any cond inputList`, as far as I can see. It's unclear what OP wants if that's not the case, I assumed a list of false values only (?)

Comment: @chi If no values satisfy the predicate, `takeWhile not bs` has the same length as `bs`, and `[True] ++ repeat False` disappears with the `zip`.